# How to track processes that use the discrete graphics card?

Tags: process, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics, switchable-graphics

How do I know which processes or background applications are using my discrete card?

By default, my laptop won't be using discrete graphic card unless gaming.

But now, even when I'm not gaming, the LED indicator shows that I'm currently using it.

How can I trace why this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sysinternals' [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) tracks which processes are using the GPU. You can enable the GPU usage column by going to the View menu, clicking "Select Columns," clicking the "Process GPU" tab, then checking "GPU usage."